# Como ocultar y mostrar un componente en angular?

Tags: angular, primeng

estoy trabajando con componente de primeNG específicamente con el p-calendar , necesito que ese componente al hacer click se oculte y muestre el otro componente con la fecha "desde Semana x.."

```js
constructor() {
        this.visible = true;
    }
    
    @ViewChild('hiddenLabel') label: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild('calendario') calendario: Calendar;
    private visible: Boolean;
    openCalendar(event: any) {
        this.calendario.inputfieldViewChild.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
    }
```

```html
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="{{anchoEntreCombobox.MD}}" *ngIf="(parametros.tipoSerie == tiposSerie['SEMANAL']['id'])">
                        <div fxFlex class="bottom-margin" >
                            <div *ngIf="!visible">
                                <span class="p-calendar p-calendar-w-btn" >
                                    <input type="text" class="p-inputtext p-component"  placeholder="Desde Semana" readonlyInput="true" value="{{weeknumber}}"/>
                                    <button type="button" (click)="openCalendar($event)" class="p-button p-component p-button-icon-only " ng-reflect-icon="pi pi-calendar">
                                        <span class="p-button-icon pi pi-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span><span aria-hidden="true" class="p-button-label"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <p>
                                <small>{{weeknumber}}</small>
                            </p>
                            <p-calendar #calendario placeholder="Desde Semana" [showWeek]="true"  
                            [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true" yearRange="2006:2022" showButtonBar="true"
                            [(ngModel)]="values" selectionMode="range" [showIcon]="true" (onSelect)="select($event)">
                            </p-calendar>
                        </div>
                  </div>
```

[image: Funcionamiento]

como se ve en la imagen tengo 2 p-calendar , el que tiene la flecha azul es el principal el cual busco la fecha , en ese si hacemos click buscamos una fecha , se oculta y queda la "semana x" en el otro componente(la flecha roja)

Answer (score 0):

para ocultar y mostrar lo mejor es usar containers y templates:

```
    <ng-container *ngIf="!dateSelect else calendarComplete">
      <p-calendar formControlName="dateSelect"></p-calendar>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #calendarComplete>
      <p-calendar formControlName="dateFull"></p-calendar>
    </ng-template>
```

En este ejemplo uso FormControls dentro de un formGroup... podrias usar ngModel

Comment: Estuve probando con un  `(click)="visible=false"` se oculta bien pero pierde el foco antes de que pueda elegir la fecha ...